# How can I load a cursor group from resource file in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, resources

I'm trying to load a custom cursor from a resource file (.rc) in Visual C++ (Windows). The resource is being properly compiled into my main .exe because I can successfully load other resource types (ie. custom resource types like "PNG").

In my .rc file I have:

```
#define IDI_CURSOR1 1000

IDI_CURSOR1 CURSOR "Resources\\Cursors\\MainCursor.cur"
```

In my .cpp file I have:

```
HCURSOR mainCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDI_CURSOR1 ) );
```

But `LoadCursor()` always returns `NULL`. Calling `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32( GetLastError() )` returns "The specified resource type cannot be found in the resource file."

Now, I tried to load it using:

```
FindResource( NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDI_CURSOR1 ), L"CURSOR" );
```

but I get the same error.

After digging around I found a way to print all resources in my module and I found my cursor. It is being loaded but as type "12" which according to this: http://www.csn.ul.ie/~caolan/pub/winresdump/winresdump/doc/resfmt.txt is a `RT_GROUP_CURSOR`. There is also a `RT_CURSOR` on there which is type "1". As a confirmation, I tried to find the resource again using:

```
 FindResource( NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDI_CURSOR1 ), "#12" );
```

and did find it with no errors.

Ok, so the cursor is being loaded but `LoadCursor()` doesn't seem to be looking for type "12". What type is it looking for and how do I get `CURSOR` to map to the correct type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should have the instance argument defined as well for your custom cursor, normally when you load standard cursors it is OK to have NULL as first argument but not for custom ones.

e.g.

```
LoadCursor( hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDI_CURSOR1 ) );
```

Comment: Scratch that, this is another case of brain deadness. I was using the module handle instead of the instance handle. You were right. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. To load a custom cursors Resource type should `#12`. Which means `RT_GROUP_CURSOR`. Use this resource type in your code instead of `RT_CURSOR`